# jQuery internet explorer to get "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

When running the following code Internet Explorer 8 gives the error "Object doesn't support this property or method":

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("input[name='first_name'], input[name='last_name']").not(".input-skippable").change(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(".input-skippable")) {
      if($(this).val().trim().length > 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("error");
      }
    }
  });
  $("input[name='first_name']").change();
});
```

The line that errors is the one with "if($(this).val().trim().length > 0) {".

It seems like it has to do with the val() then trim().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `.val()` returns a string, breaking the jQuery chain, meaning you can't then apply any more jQuery methods (`.trim()`). The other problem is that `trim` is a method of the jQuery object itself, where the value to be trimmed must be passed as an argument (`$.trim(value)`), rather than a method to be chained to a jQuery function call (`$(value).trim()`). The correct code for obtaining the trimmed length of the value would be as follows:

```
$.trim($(this).val()).length
```

**EDIT:** This answer assumes the unavailability of ECMAscript 5's [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method for strings — which allows the OP's code to work in IE9 and most modern browsers — but is unavailable in IE8 and below. Instead, it relies on [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Comment: This is not true, Vanilla JavaScript also has `trim` method, what OP has used is `trim` method of String object.

Comment: @undefined everything I just wrote is true, and the solution solves the OP's question. It's also true that Vanilla JavaScript provides a `trim` method for String as of ECMAscript version 5, but that isn't supported by IE < 9 — hence the OP's question.

Comment: I put this as the accepted answer since it's the most complete one even though the answer by @undefined was quicker.

Comment: Your provided solution works, of course, I meant this part _meaning you can't then apply any more jQuery methods (.trim()). The other problem is that trim is a method of the jQuery object itself.._. Which is not true.

Comment: I did use the .trim() function as I thought it was used in jQuery. I knew that Internet Explorer doesn't support trim() natively.

Comment: @emilhem that's what I thought — unlike other libraries like [underscore.js](http://www.underscorejs.org), jQuery is a bit ambiguous about when it stops chaining and returns primitive objects. The difference between `$.method` and `$().method` is also a quirky API decision (prone to typos!).

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below do not support the `trim` method, you can use jQuery `$.trim` utility function.

```
if( $.trim( this.value ).length > 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong
`if($(this).val().trim().length > 0) {`

Change to

`if($.trim($(this).val())!="") {`